# R (debian): Is there a way to combine install.packages() with auto-apt or similar so that missing dependencies will be installed automatically?

Tags: debian, installation, r

I have R installed on a debian system. Often there is difficulty finding all the dependencies of a certain CRAN package. Is there a way to combine install.packages() with auto-apt or similar so that missing dependencies will be installed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to.

```
install.packages("package", dependencies=TRUE)
```

will install all the CRAN dependencies for you.

Comment: That only takes care of CRAN dependencies, my problem is with deb dependencies. I have a vague memory of doing something with that which worked, log ago, but cant remember how.